# Firebase Cloud Funtion call trigger mutiple time

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I using firebase and create trigger listen any change from student document. If student document change, i push any change to rest api. But my function call mutiple time.

Bellow is my function :

```
exports.triggerTimeStudent= functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/class/{classId}/students/{studentId}')
    .onUpdate( (change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data();
        const previousValue = change.before.data();
        const {update_at: afterStatus} = newValue;
        const {update_at: beforeStatus} = previousValue;
        const {name: name} = newValue;
        if (afterStatus !== beforeStatus) {
                try {

                    var data = {
                        "student_name": name,
                    };
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("Inside Rest API");
                    return rest.post("https://example.com/api/v1/student/add-by-name", {
                        ...studentServiceRestOption, ...{
                            body:  JSON.stringify(data)
                        }
                    });

                } catch (error) {
                    return res
                        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .send(buildError({
                            code: errorCode.SYSTEM_ERROR,
                            message: error.message,
                        }))
                }

        }
```

I can't know why function call mutiple time. I want call only time. My function incorrect. Please help

Comment: I would expect that this function not work at all.  You can't call `res.send()` in a Firestore function.  That's only for HTTP functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson
But it create success student name in https://example.com/api/v1/student/add-by-name . It only call res.send when server error. It create success but it create two time. It mean it call trigger two time. I don't know why ? Please help

Comment: @DougStevenson When i remove try catch and only call rest , it created success but create dulicate data. When i view log in Cloud Funtion , it call mutiple time trigger

Comment: @DougStevenson How to call rest api in trigger ?

Answer (score 1):

By design, Cloud Functions **may** be called multiple times. It is up to you to ensure that your functions can handle [being retried](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE).

However, your error likely stems from the value of the `update_at` key. If this key's value is an object, the `===` and `!==` operands aren't going to produce the correct result. You will need to check the object for an "isEqual" or "equals" method, or use a third-party solution such as [`_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual).

Below, I have refactored your code for performance and ease-of-use. I could not identify the `rest` object you were using for the API call, so I have substituted it for `node-fetch`.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch"); // see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

// for object equality tests
// const isEqual = require("lodash.isequal");

const STUDENT_SERVICE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}

exports.triggerTimeStudent= functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}/class/{classId}/students/{studentId}")
    .onUpdate( (change, context) => {
        const beforeStatus = change.before.get("update_at"); // accessed directly for performance
        const afterStatus = change.after.get("update_at");

        // If beforeStatus and afterStatus are
        //  - string, boolean, int, etc.: use beforeStatus === afterStatus
        //  - firestore.Timestamp objects: use beforeStatus.isEqual(afterStatus)
        //  - custom objects: use isEqual(beforeStatus, afterStatus) from lodash/underscore packages

        if (beforeStatus === afterStatus) {
          console.log("Status unmodified. Ignored change.");
          return;
        }

        const data = {
          student_name: change.after.get("name")
        }

        console.log("Making API call...", { data });

        const fetchOptions = {
          ...STUDENT_SERVICE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }

        return fetch("https://example.com/api/v1/student/add-by-name", fetchOptions)
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { // see "Handling client and server errors" in "node-fetch" docs
              throw new Error("Unexpected API response: " + response.statusText);
            }

            console.log("Successfully added student!");
          })
          .catch(error => console.error("Failed to add student!", { error, fetchOptions }));
    });
```

**Note:** You can view the logged messages from Cloud Functions in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/functions/logs?search=&severity=DEBUG).